# Can ghee replace butter in lemon curd?

Tags: baking, substitutions, butter, dessert, ghee

My mother-in-law believes she is allergic to milk solids, but that ghee has the solids removed.  She loves lemon meringue pie.  The lemon curd in the pie calls for butter.  Can I substitute ghee successfully?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can; for example, from [Charlotte's Lively Kitchen](https://charlotteslivelykitchen.com/lemon-curd/) we have the following remark:

> **Can lemon curd be made with clarified butter?**
>
> OK, this is maybe a slightly unusual recipe adjustment to have tested.
> However, I decided that as lemon curd is such a classic recipe, I’d
> see how it was made in an old Victorian cookbook I was given by my
> Granny, and that recipe used clarified butter so I thought I’d give it
> a try.
>
> It was delicious. However, I didn’t think it tasted like lemon curd as
> we know it today so I decided to stick with regular butter.

Note that butter is *about* 80% fat, 18% water, and 2% milk solids (varies according to the butter).  So, you may wish to reduce the amount of ghee and adjust the moisture content based on your recipe.